# Android Market auto restore apps not working

Tags: google-play-store, restore, factory-reset

After some problems I had to restore my phone. Before doing it I had enabled the option of google's security copy. Now I've linked my google account and market does nothing, it doesn't restore apps. So I've decided to enter the market through the browser and in "My market account" I could only see the three apps that are native to the phone (youtube, gmail and google maps). How can I get all the apps I had before?

Thanks,
Diego

Comment: Did you look in your "library"? https://market.android.com/mylibrary I recently did a factory reset and I can see all of the apps that I'd previously had installed, not just the ones I've only just gotten around to.

Comment: Yes yes!!! They are there, thanks. Please post this as an answer.

Comment: Sure. Done. (I was happy to find them there, too.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you look in your "[Library](https://play.google.com/apps)"?

I recently did a factory reset and I can see all of the apps that I'd previously had installed, not just the ones I've only just gotten around to.

Comment: this is cool, i didn't know you could do this! is there any way to do it from the phone market?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, if you didn't pay for them, i don't believe the market saves any record of your downloads. If they cost money, the should show up under `My apps` in the market after a fresh system wipe, but free apps should be backed up with [Titanium Backup](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup&feature=search_result) or [Astro File Manager](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.metago.astro&feature=search_result), both allow you to simply reinstall your apps at any time.

Comment: I would add AppBrain (https://market.android.com/details?id=com.appspot.swisscodemonkeys.apps ) to that list.  Combined with Fast Web Installer (https://market.android.com/details?id=com.appspot.swisscodemonkeys.apppusher ) it allows you to create a list of your apps either by syncing from the phone, or via their web site.  You can then re-install them onto your device with one click.

Comment: @jlehenbauer Actually, Market saves your installed apps, because when I got my Galaxy Tab 10.1 it automatically installed the ~80 apps I had on my Galaxy S. But this has never happened then I've wiped the phone (for example when flashing). Maybe it only works for new devices that use the same Google account?

Comment: Yes, I know about that apps but they need root access and my reinstall was made by tech service, if I rooted my phone to backup they wouldn't take it.

Comment: cool! i didn't know about @Al's solution, i like it. And only Titanium Backup requires root, Astro doesn't.